# Dynamically Updating PHP HTML Table with AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a PHP HTML table loads in data from a SQL database. How would I be able to update that data using an onclick button function?

Basically I want the whole data to be updated so instead of the SQL query looking for the month of January, I want to display data from March.

I have setup php files to look for different datasets, im just not sure on how to use Ajax to refresh the table.

Here is a snippet of what im using to populate the HTML table:

```
        echo "<table class='content-table is-striped'>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Person</th>";
            echo "<th>Weight (Kg)</th>";
            echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "</tr>";


        $month = date('m');


        if ($month == "01") {
            $sql = "SELECT * from WeightTracker WHERE person = 'Ayush' AND date_month = 'January' ORDER BY weight_date DESC";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $x = 0;
            if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
              while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
                if ($x % 2 == 0) {
                  $bgcolour = oddbg;
                }
                else {
                  $bgcolour = evenbg;
                }
                  echo "<tbody><tr class='$bgcolour'><td>". $row["person"] ."</td><td>". $row["kg"] ."</td><td>". $row["weight_date"] ."</td></tr></tbody>";
                  $x++;
              }
              echo "</table>";
            }
            else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
        }
```

Any ideas would be awesome!

Comment: You could add a list of options/dropdown buttons of all the months and all the data will be loaded in each option respectively. Then, use javascript to switch between those options upon selection. It might not be what you were looking for but it'll work.

Comment: @azula, that's exactly what I was thinking of doing. I just don't know how to switch the data with javascript if that makes sense